# Scelta corretta del genere

Tags: word-choice, gender

Ciao a tutti!
Oggi mi sono imbattuta in questo quesito:

"fine" può essere sia maschile che femminile!?

Per esempio: "il fine giustifica i mezzi", ma "la fine del film"...

Quando "fine" è maschile e quando femminile?
Grazie tante!

Comment: L'hai cercato su un dizionario?

Comment: *Fine* come *scopo* è maschile, *fine* come *termine* è femminile. Ogni buon dizionario dovrebbe spiegare la distinzione.

Answer (score 7):

***[Il fine - la fine](http://www.mauriziopistone.it/testi/discussioni/storieparole_il_la_fine.html)***

> - ***Finis in latino era maschile;*** e tale rimane spesso nella lingua antica. Nella Vita Nova di Dante abbiamo:
>
>   - *E acciò che questa canzone paia rimanere più vedova dopo lo suo fine, la dividerò prima che io la scriva (XXXI)*

ma anche:

> - *quasi dal principio del suo anno nono apparve a me, ed io la vidi quasi da la fine del mio nono (II)*

***Nella lingua moderna***  si preferisce il femminile nel senso di «parte terminale», il maschile nel senso di «scopo». Così propone già il Tommaseo; ma non è regola assoluta.

> - ***Il fine nel senso di «conclusione di un testo» è frequente in ogni epoca, forse sotto l’influenza della lingua dotta;*** e qualche vecchio professore chiama ancora campanella del finis il suono liberatorio che ci manda tutti a casa (questa e la lectio brevis restano l’unico latino che s’ode senza noia e si intende senza sforzo).
> - Quindi il fine settimana dell’uso corrente come traduzione di weekend mi sembra che possa stare benissimo, come il lieto fine di ogni buona storia e il buon fine di ogni assegno che si rispetti.

(www.mauriziopistone.it)

Comment: Altro esempio di “fine” maschile nel senso di “conclusione”: “Questo è il fin di chi fa mal” (Lorenzo da Ponte, finale del *Don Giovanni*).

Answer (score 1):

La "rule of thumb":

Fine = End è femminile;
Fine = Goal/Objective è maschile.

Per i dettagli fai riferimento alla risposta di @Gio.