# Il fine settimana/weekend: perché è maschile invece di femminile?

Tags: word-usage, grammar, articles, gender

Perché si usa "il fine settimana/weekend" invece di "la fine settimana/weekend", siccome il fine significa metà o obiettivo mentre la fine significa fondo o conclusione?

Comment: Secondo te non *è* l'obiettivo della settimana? :D

Comment: Vedi questa spiegazione: http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/fine-finestra-di-approfondimento_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/.

Comment: [Questo link](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/espressioni-fine-vita-fine-anno-fine-mese-fi) sembra rilevante. Se nessun altro prende il colpo cercherò di scrivere una risposta domani prima di sera.

Comment: @DenisNardin: E la tua risposta?

Comment: @Charo Impegni di lavoro mi hanno impedito... Provo a scriverla ora :)

Comment: Sig. Poloni: buon punto!

Comment: Perché è stata chiusa la questione? Non è un duplicato.

Comment: @DenisNardin: Non capisco cosa significa che è stata chiusa "by Community", ma l'ho riaperta.

Comment: Di parte della questione si era parlato già [qui](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/7974/scelta-corretta-del-genere).

Comment: @DaG Non sono d'accordo. L'OP sa chiaramente le regole per il genere della parola *fine*, la domanda qui è quale sia la giustificazione per il genere di *fine settimana*.

Answer (score 3):

[Questo articolo](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/espressioni-fine-vita-fine-anno-fine-mese-fi) entra in molti dettagli proprio riguardo al genere dell'espressione *fine settimana*. Nel seguito cerco di presentare un breve riassunto dei punti salienti.

Innanzitutto, il termine *fine settimana* è un calco dall'inglese *weekend* e di conseguenza ne assume il genere. Come [già discusso in questo sito](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/8517/gender-of-foreign-words) i termini stranieri importati in italiano tendono ad assumere il genere di un iperonimo, vale a dire di una parola che esprime un significato più ampio (e.g. *chat* da chiacchierata). Perché dunque *weekend* (e di conseguenza *finesettimana*) ha assunto il genere maschile, invece del femminile (da *fine* o *settimana*)?

Sembra che due siano i motivi di ciò:

- La parola *fine* ha un genere storicamente indeterminato in italiano. È vero che *fine* nel senso di *termine* può assumere solo il genere femminile, ma nell'originale latino (e in molte attestazioni in italiano antico), *finis,is* [preferiva il genere maschile](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=finis). Anzi, la forma femminile sembra essere riservata solo al significato di "istante finale" (in contrapposizione a "periodo conclusivo")[1].
- Il termine *weekend* sembra avere come iperonimo principale *periodo*, *intervallo di tempo* piuttosto che *fine* e *conclusione*, e perciò aver assunto il genere maschile, secondo la regola precedentemente detta.

[1] Non riesco a trovare un riferimento preciso a questo nel Lewis-Short ma mi fido abbastanza dell'Accademia della Crusca e l'osservazione si conforma ai miei distanti ricordi di latino. Se qualcuno avesse un riferimento migliore sarebbe molto apprezzato.

Answer (score -1):

L'Accademia della Crusca spiega che probabilmente è mutuato dall'inglese
 http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/genere-fine-settimana.

Comment: Interessante, ma così si sposta solo il problema a perché quel termine inglese sia usato in italiano al maschile...

Comment: Perché è norma nella lingua italiana portare quasi tutti i "prestiti stranieri" al maschile. Ad esempio business, se inteso come "attività" andrebbe al femminile ma così non è. Body building, yogurt, tutto al maschile. Resta che sarebbe semanticamente e grammaticalmente corretto. Rari esempi sono "emoticon", "brexit". Il maschile si assegna "automaticamente" quando il termine straniero non rientra in una serie già ben delineata. Ad esempio, che si dica auto, o macchina, dall'inglese noi diciamo "la city car"

Comment: Questa presunta "norma" sulla prevalenza del maschile è già stata discussa [qui](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/8517/gender-of-foreign-words) e sostanzialmente confutata.